# how to enable BEEPsound in RHEL?

Tags: linux

On my new RHEL 6.4 machine, the beep sound is disabled. How can I enable it?

Comment: Does `modprobe pc_spkr` help? Also check that `pc_spkr` isn't blacklisted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the module on RHEL/CentOS/Fedora is `pcspkr`. You can check if it's loaded using `lsmod`:

```
$ lsmod | grep pcspkr
```

If it doesn't return anything then it isn't loaded. You can load it with this command:

```
$ sudo modprobe pcspkr
```

You can use `modinfo` to find out info about a driver too. On CentOS 6.4:

```
$ modinfo pcspkr
filename:       /lib/modules/2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.x86_64/kernel/drivers/input/misc/pcspkr.ko
license:        GPL
description:    PC Speaker beeper driver
author:         Vojtech Pavlik <vojtech@ucw.cz>
srcversion:     1CA27E173B6361EE7DCACEF
depends:        
vermagic:       2.6.32-358.11.1.el6.x86_64 SMP mod_unload modversions
```

Comment: Right. My bad :)

Comment: @JosephR. - what's a underscore anyway 8-).